# JavaScript que se repite

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Soy nuevo en la programación de javascript y tome un código fuente de un app que muestra un mapa con leaflet.  Modifique el código según mis necesidades, pero después que carga todos los marker sobre el mapa; vuelve a iniciar el código desde la primera función.  Me di cuenta por que llene de 'alert' el código y después de cargar las marcas en el mapa vuelve a cargar el mapa dejando todo como al inicio.
La función 'getNuevomapa()' es la que carga el mapa y verán que incluí un mensaje "alert('Entre a getNuevomapa')" que como comento se repite después de terminar la ejecución y al cargar nuevamente el mapa ya no se muestran los marker.
Ya tengo varias semanas con este problema y agradezco su apoyo a resolverlo.

Código:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var mapa = document.getElementById('mi-mapa');
    var autoRefresh = false;
    var viewingAllRoutes = true;
    var mapaTempus = getNuevoMapa();
    var $empresa_id = jQuery("#empresa_id").val();

    // Carga los grupos
    cargaGrupos();

    $('#cbx_grupo').on('change', function () {
        var grupo_id = $('#cbx_grupo').val()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'funciones/listas.php',
            data: {'tipo': 'usuarios', 'grupo_id': grupo_id}
        })
                .done(function (lista_usuarios) {
                    $('#cbx_usuario').html(lista_usuarios);
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    alert('Hubo un errror al cargar la lista de Usuarios');
                })
    });

    $('#bt_filtrar').on('click', function () {
        var grupo_id = $('#cbx_grupo').val();
        var usuario_id = $('#cbx_usuario').val();
        console.log('Grupo: ' + grupo_id);
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'funciones/listas.php',
            data: {'tipo': 'ubicacion', 'grupo_id': grupo_id, 'usuario_id': usuario_id}
        })
                .done(function (lista_usuarios_mapa) {
                    loadGPSLocations(lista_usuarios_mapa);
                    alert('Termine, a ver que pasa');
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    alert('Hubo un errror al cargar la lista de Usuarios del Mapa');
                })
    });

    function cargaGrupos() {
        alert('cargaGrupos()');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'funciones/listas.php',
            data: {'tipo': 'grupos', empresa_id: $empresa_id}
        })
                .done(function (lista_grupos) {
                    $('#cbx_grupo').html(lista_grupos);
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    alert('Hubo un errror al cargar la lista de Grupos');
                })
    }

    function loadGPSLocations(json) {
        alert('loadGPSLocations(json)');
        if (json.length == 0) {
            showPermanentMessage('No hay datos para dar seguimiento');
            mapa.innerHTML = '';
        } else {
            var finalLocation = false;
            var counter = 0;
            var locationArray = [];
            // iterate through the locations and create map markers for each location
            $(json.locations).each(function (key, value) {
                var latitud = $(this).attr('trn_latitud');
                var longitud = $(this).attr('trn_longitud');
                var tempLocation = new L.LatLng(latitud, longitud);
                locationArray.push(tempLocation);
                counter++;
                // want to set the map center on the last location
                if (counter == $(json.locations).length) {
                    //gpsTrackerMap.setView(tempLocation, zoom);  if using fixed zoom
                    finalLocation = true;

                    if (!viewingAllRoutes) {
//                        displayCityName(latitud, longitud);
                    }
                }
                var marker = createMarker(
                        latitud,
                        longitud,
                        $(this).attr('trn_velocidad'),
                        $(this).attr('trn_direccion_gps'),
                        $(this).attr('trn_distancia'),
                        $(this).attr('trn_fecha_tiempo_gps'),
                        $(this).attr('usr_nombre'),
                        $(this).attr('trn_sesion_id'),
                        $(this).attr('trn_exactitud'),
                        mapaTempus, finalLocation);
            });
            // fit markers within window
            var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(locationArray);
            mapaTempus.fitBounds(bounds);

            // restarting interval here in case we are coming from viewing all routes
            alert('autoRefresh: ' + autoRefresh);
            if (autoRefresh) {
                restartInterval();
            }

        }
    }

    function createMarker(latitude, longitude, speed, direction, distance, gpsTime,
            userName, sessionID, accuracy, mapaTempus, finalLocation) {
        alert('latitud: ' + latitude + ' long: ' + longitude + ' vel: ' + speed +
                ' direc: ' + direction + ' dist: ' + distance +
                ' gpsTimee: ' + gpsTime + ' name: ' + userName +
                ' session: ' + sessionID + ' exact: ' + accuracy);
        var iconUrl;
        if (finalLocation) {
            iconUrl = 'images/coolred_small.png';
        } else {
            iconUrl = 'images/coolgreen2_small.png';
        }

        var markerIcon = new L.Icon({
            iconUrl: iconUrl,
            shadowUrl: 'images/coolshadow_small.png',
            iconSize: [12, 20],
            shadowSize: [22, 20],
            iconAnchor: [6, 20],
            shadowAnchor: [6, 20],
            popupAnchor: [-3, -25]
        });

        var lastMarker = "</td></tr>";

        // when a user clicks on last marker, let them know it's final one
        if (finalLocation) {
            lastMarker = "</td></tr><tr><td align=left>&nbsp;</td><td><b>Final location</b></td></tr>";
        }

        // convert from meters to feet
        accuracy = parseInt(accuracy * 3.28);

        var popupWindowText = "<table border=0 style=\"font-size:95%;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000;\">" +
                "<tr><td align=right>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td rowspan=2 align=right>" +
                "<img src=images/" + getCompassImage(direction) + ".jpg alt= />" + lastMarker +
                "<tr><td align=right>Speed:&nbsp;</td><td>" + speed + " mph</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td align=right>Distance:&nbsp;</td><td>" + distance + " mi</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td align=right>Time:&nbsp;</td><td colspan=2>" + gpsTime + "</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td align=right>Name:&nbsp;</td><td>" + userName + "</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td align=right>Accuracy:&nbsp;</td><td>" + accuracy + " ft</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>";

        var gpstMarker;
        var title = userName + " - " + gpsTime;

        // make sure the final red marker always displays on top 
        if (finalLocation) {
            gpstMarker = new L.marker(new L.LatLng(latitude, longitude), {title: title, icon: markerIcon, zIndexOffset: 999}).bindPopup(popupWindowText).addTo(mapaTempus);
        } else {
            gpstMarker = new L.marker(new L.LatLng(latitude, longitude), {title: title, icon: markerIcon}).bindPopup(popupWindowText).addTo(mapaTempus);
        }
    }

    function getCompassImage(azimuth) {
        if ((azimuth >= 337 && azimuth <= 360) || (azimuth >= 0 && azimuth < 23))
            return "compassN";
        if (azimuth >= 23 && azimuth < 68)
            return "compassNE";
        if (azimuth >= 68 && azimuth < 113)
            return "compassE";
        if (azimuth >= 113 && azimuth < 158)
            return "compassSE";
        if (azimuth >= 158 && azimuth < 203)
            return "compassS";
        if (azimuth >= 203 && azimuth < 248)
            return "compassSW";
        if (azimuth >= 248 && azimuth < 293)
            return "compassW";
        if (azimuth >= 293 && azimuth < 337)
            return "compassNW";

        return "";
    }

    function showPermanentMessage(message) {
        alert('showPermanentMessage(message)');
        $('#messages').html(message);
    }


    function getNuevoMapa() {
        alert('Entre a getNuevomapa');
        // use leaflet (http://leafletjs.com/) to create our map and map layers
        var mapaTempus = new L.map('mi-mapa', {
            center: [9.0689430, -79.4519100],
            zoom: 15,
            scrollWheelZoon: false
        });
//        var capaOpenStreetMapsRelieve = new L.tileLayer('http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg');
        var openStreetMapsURL = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +
                '{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
        var openStreetMapsLayer = new L.TileLayer(openStreetMapsURL,
                {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'});
        mapaTempus.addControl(openStreetMapsLayer);
        return mapaTempus;
    }

});
```